# Swift Application Initialization not Working

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, initialization, xib

I am making a Cocoa app, and previously, all my code was in AppDelegate.swift. I wanted to write an extension but it wouldn't let me do it there, so I created another class, and pasted my code in it. After reconnecting all my objects to their respective Xibs (sorry if my technical jargon is a bit off) the code is the exact same except for the initialization. I used 
`func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)`
which worked previously in AppDelegate.Swift but now no longer gets executed. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out I just needed to add a delegate from my new class to AppDelegate.swift. Now at least the launching works, but now unfortunately everything I write there is crashing. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand well what your problem is, anyway you could follow these steps:

1. Create your class (suppose to be a `UIViewController`)
2. Connect your class with a `ViewController` in your `main storyboard` (make sure your app uses that storyboard in Project Settings)
3. To get started with your code use methods like `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` and so on, which are triggered automatically, like `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you used before.

Comment: I think you were basically right; rather than using didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I'm now using awakeFromNib(), which I understand to be more or less an equivalent statement.

Comment: @Uzebeckatrente be careful anyway because any of those methods are triggered at specific different moments, meaning that firing some code not at the appropriate time may cause really bad behaviours and crashes. My advice is to understand how all these works and decide which one fits your case, actually `awakeFromNib()` may not be the best choice in my opinion.